# ShowTimePicker i need to show the time picker on text field

Tags: flutter, mobile

```
defultFormField(
                          controller: timeController,
                          onSubmit: () {},
                          onTap: () {
                            showTimePicker(
                              useRootNavigator: true,
                              context: context,
                              initialTime: TimeOfDay.now(),
                            ).then((value) {
                              print(value);
                            });
                          },

and this is the components 

   Widget defultFormField({
  required  Function onTap,
  required Function onSubmit,
  required TextEditingController controller,
  // required TextInputType type,
  required String text,
  required IconData prefix,
  required Function valedate,
}) =>
    TextFormField(
      controller: controller,
      // keyboardType: type,
      onTap: () {},
      onFieldSubmitted: (s) {},
      validator: (s) {
        valedate();
      },
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
        labelText: text,
        prefixIcon: Icon(prefix),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code hope its helpful to you. Or you can used [this](https://pub.dev/packages/datetime_picker_formfield) package also.

Declare TimeOfDay class

```
TimeOfDay _time = TimeOfDay(hour: 00, minute: 00);
```

Create function for TimePicker

```
void _selectTime() async {
    final TimeOfDay? newTime = await showTimePicker(
      context: context,
      initialTime: _time,
    );
    if (newTime != null) {
      setState(() {
        _time = newTime;
      });
    }
  }
```

Your Widget

```
Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: TextFormField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              hintText: 'Select Time',
              border: OutlineInputBorder(),
            ),
            onTap: _selectTime,
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 8),
        Text(
          'Selected time: ${_time.format(context)}',
        ),
      ],
    ),
```