# add time picker to flutter code causes error

Tags: flutter, dart, timepicker

I use below code to add time picker:

```
final TimeOfDay newTime = await showTimePicker(
  context: context,
  initialTime: TimeOfDay(hour: 7, minute: 15),
);
```

But I give below error:

A value of type 'TimeOfDay?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'TimeOfDay'.
Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'TimeOfDay'

Comment: try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69466708/13997210) answer hope its helpful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply change to:

```dart
final TimeOfDay? newTime = await showTimePicker(
  context: context,
  initialTime: TimeOfDay(hour: 7, minute: 15),
);
```

Then you may want to unwrap the optional result:

```dart
if (newTime != null) {
  // do stuff with newTime
}
```